# The "Symfony\Component\Debug\Exception\FatalThrowableError"

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-6

I have Laravel 6 project and when I use Barryvdh\DomPDF to load the pdf into my public folder I get the message error below

**The "Symfony\Component\Debug\Exception\FatalThrowableError" class is deprecated since Symfony 4.4. 16384**

This is my Controller function

```
<?php

namespace App\Http\Controllers\MyController;

use App\Http\Controllers\Controller;
use Illuminate\Http\Request;
use PDF;

class MyController extends Controller
{

  function load_pdf(Request $req){

    $data = [ 'Message' => 'MY PDF'];
    PDF::loadView('pdf', $data)->save(public_path())->stream('mypdf.pdf');
    return "It's Okey";

   }
}
```

'pdf' it's a view in the views folder
 and i already add this to my app file in config folder

```
'providers' => [
    ....
    Barryvdh\DomPDF\ServiceProvider::class,
],

'aliases' => [
    ....
    'PDF' => Barryvdh\DomPDF\Facade::class,
]
```

Any solution ??

Comment: There's a bug open on `Barryvdh\DomPDF`'s GitHub page, but it hasn't been addressed yet. So it has nothing to do with your code, and everything to do with the package and it's dependencies.

Comment: so there is no solution for this :/

Comment: Not that I know of. It's a discrepancy between versions of Symfony. You can try upgrading all packages and see if that helps.

Answer (score 0):

For information, you should put your code in a try/catch bloc to handle the exception and know more about the error.

Answer (score 0):

I had an error as I know it in a pdf and it is resolved with the tags `<pre> </pre>` since this is rendering the html in the pdf, which happens when you send html from the db, for the pdf format . I solve it this way, I hope you do too.

```
<pre>{!!$response->data!!}</pre>
```